# SwiftUI: Why do I get duplicates in my TabView?

Tags: swiftui, duplicates, navigationbar, swiftui-tabview

I am trying to add a navigation bar to my SwiftUI app using a TabView like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isLoggedIn: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            if isLoggedIn {
                LogInPage()
            } else {
                TabView{
                    HomeScreen()
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "house")
                            Text("Hem")
                        }
                    BookingsScreen()
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "book")
                            Text("Bokningar")
                        }
                    ProfileScreen()
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "person")
                            Text("Profil")
                        }
                }
            }
           
        }
    }
}
```

But I get two duplicates of the 'house' icon and the text "Home" under it, and I also get another icon with three dots and the text "More" under it, literally from nowhere as I haven't even mentioned anything else then a house, a book and a person. And when I press on it (the three dots) it shows a list of "person.fill" with the text "Profile" next to it. Here is an some image of how my TabView looks like and when I press on the three dots:

[image: unexpected behaviour]

Comment: Does it help to create a `Label` inside the `.tabItem` closure?

Comment: You mean replacing my `Text()` and `Image()` with a `Label?` Then no, it does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the views that duplicate in a VStack

```
       TabView{
            VStack{
                HomeScreen()
            }
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "house")
                        Text("Hem")
                    }
                BookingsScreen()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "book")
                        Text("Bokningar")
                    }
           VStack {
                ProfileScreen()
           }
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "person")
                        Text("Profil")
                    }
            }
```

Comment: It will mess up my layout even more. By wrapping it inside a Stack I can no longer see any navigation bar at all. @lorem ipsum

Comment: @AranAli the TabView should always be on top. It is an error if it is inside a NavigationStack/View. Each tab needs its own, they must be mutually exclusive. This is per HIG.

Comment: Excuse me, yes you are right. Wrapping it inside a VStack do actually solve my problem. Silly me who misunderstood you at first...